# MSGraph subscription notification not received

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

We are using Graph API in our mobile app to subscribe for changes in users calendar items. We use the subscription feature of graph API with webhooks. However we notice that some times (approx 10%) our server webhook is not invoked at all.

What will be the right way to further troubleshoot this?
We have all the necessary details like SubscriptionID, EventID, Timestamp etc but are not sure where we can report/check this?

We would really appreciate any pointers.

Comment: I have a couple of questions for clarification:
1. When did the 10% drop start? Is it deterministically happening now? How did you track that? 
2. Did you check whether your server is healthy during that 10% of the time?
3. Does it happen to 1 subscription, or across multiple subscriptions? 
4. Could you give some samples when notifications are not received?